# Can dialogflow became like an omnychat tool?

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I setup a bot in DialogFlow that could redirect the current chat to more than one person so that they could continue with the conversation? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

At this moment that is not supported by Dialogflow out of the box. Dialogflow has provided [examples](https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs) that allow you to do it using a custom implementation or you can integrate Dialogflow with a platform that does offer support for human handover such as [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/chatbot-human-handoff/).